# Referencing an excel cell that has a variable formula on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have built an appraisal sheet that allows you select your name from a drop down and all other details about you pop up in other cells. One of such detail will either pop up as Yes or No, depending on whether you manage a team. Now, my VBA code references this cell (F8) that has Yes or No, and it hides or unhides some rows depending on the value of F8. The problem here is that F8 has a formula that was used to derive its value (A Vlookup) and the formula reads

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$6,Data!$E:$I,5,0),"")
```

My VBA code no longer hides or unhides any cells since I started using a formula in F8. My VBA code is below

```
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("F8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "Yes": Rows("25:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "No": Rows("25:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        End Select


End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume this is in a Worksheet_Change event.  That does not fire on calculation.  You will need to point at C6 Changing not F8

Comment: @ScottCraner But if a value in `Data!$E:$I` changes and `$C$6` stays the same then the result of the formula could still change from `Yes` to `No` and the event still doesn't trigger ^^. So you would have to watch addionally for changes is `Data!$E:$I`.

Comment: @ScottCraner and PEH

C6 is a drop down of names that changes. So users are supposed to select names on C6. The value of C6 affects F8 to change between Yes and No using the Vlookup formula. I need my VBA to reference F8 so that if the value is No, Rows 25 and 26 are hidden and vise versa if it is No.

How can I achieve this with the code I have pasted above?

Comment: `If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C6"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Then `Select Case Range("F8")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I have tried this and is giving me a compile error

Answer (score 0):

1. `Range(Target.Address)` is actually the same as `Target`, don't over complicate things.
2. And `ActiveSheet` is called `ActiveSheet` because that sheet is **active**. So to `.Activate` an aleady active sheet `ActiveSheet.Activate` is pretty useless :)

The following should do it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("C6"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Me.Range("F8").Value
            Case Is = "Yes": Me.Rows("25:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Is = "No": Me.Rows("25:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

But note that if the values in `Data!$E:$I` that you lookup change then the formula result of F8 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$6,Data!$E:$I,5,0),"")` will change without triggering the `Worksheet_Change` event! So be aware that after changing something in the `Data` sheet you need to rewrite/re-select the value in C6, to trigger the macro again.